# Typescript 0.8.2 - Compile on save with specified output file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to configure a typescript solution to both compile-on-save (which I have working fine) in addition to specifying the output directory.

Is this even possible? I see in the typescript targets file that there's a check to see an --out file is specified. If it is, compile-on-save is disabled.

```
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled Condition="'$(TypeScriptEnableCompileOnSave)' != 'false' and '$(TypeScriptOutFile)' == ''">true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
```

Comment: what advantage you are getting by saving it different file name instead of the default one?

Comment: Im not saving it to a different file name. The output file directive is re-used for output directory if a folder is provided instead of a file.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to get this done? I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15651172/1267778 . Received a reply that it's a limitation of the current implementation. Did you happen to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. There is an issue already logged to track this at: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/854