# Typescript: How to create definition files on save?

Tags: tfs, typescript

We are currently evaluating Typescript and the overall impression is really very good!
We are using Webessentials too, and checked the option to add all the created files to TFS. But now we ran into a problem. 
If we have a Typescript file 'class1.ts' that references 'class2.ts' (by `/// <reference path="class2.ts" />`) , I get an error "Couldn't write to file class2.js" when I save class1.ts. Obviously the compiler tries to compile class1 **and** the referenced class2 but only class1.ts is checked out.

The best fix for this would probably be to reference class.d.ts instead of class2.ts But I couldn*t find a way to automatically create definition files on save.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems when started working with TypeScript in a TFS environment.
Although your question is asking for a way to auto-generate definition files on save, your real problem is related to TFS.

**Solving your real problem:**

TFS by default works with server workspaces, which means that any edit to local file requires a check-out to be performed on the server. For this reason all local files are locked requiring an explicit check-out. Visual Studio does that for you automatically if you open the file and edit it, but it won't do that for referenced files that are not being edited directly.

The solution for that is to configure TFS to work with local workspaces, that you offer you other benefits, such as not include in "Pending changes" a .js file that was re-created without any change in its content.

I suggest read this simple article that is really clear to compare local vs server workspaces:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/11/30/team-foundation-server-trying-to-understand-server-versus-local-workspaces.aspx

When you set local workspaces you are affecting only your machine, so no changes in TFS server are needed.

To set up local workspaces in your machine:

1. Visual Studio/File/Souce control/Advanced/Workspaces
2. Select a workspace and click edit;
3. In the new screen click
4. “Advanced” Change the location to “Local”

[image: TFS set up local workspace]

After those changes all your local files will writeable, you will be able to work offline without need to to “Go online” with the solution when connected to the server again, because all your local changes (even outside VS) will be detected by TFS.
You will also have TFS entries added to the context menu in Windows Explorer that can be helpful.

**Solving the problem that you don't really need to solve - auto generate definition files:**

You don't need to solve this, but to keep coherent with the question and maybe this can be helpful to others that come to this question in the future.

To force a certain action to be performed when a specific file is saved you can associate a custom tool to your file (Visual Studio/Solution Explorer/Properties (F4)/Custom Tool) and then create a build target that execute TypeScript compiler to generate definitions.

Something like this (pseudo code, not tested):

```
<Target Name="GenerateTypeScriptDeclarationFile">
  <Exec Command="tsc --definition @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651172/typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save/16660417#16660417) for more details on how to use Custom Tools with TypeScript and MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error "Couldn't write to file class2.js" when I save class1.ts. Obviously the compiler tries to compile class1 and the referenced class2 but only class1.ts is checked out

My recommendatation here would be to checkout class2.ts as well.

If you still want auto generation of .d.ts for your files you can use a grunt task for that:
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-typescript

```
grunt.initConfig({
    ...
    typescript: {
      base: {
        src: ['path/to/typescript/files/**/*.ts'],
        dest: 'where/you/want/your/js/files',
        options: {             
          declaration: true,
        }
      }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: To checkout class2.ts as well would mean that recursively I might end with all my files checked out. This is something I want to avoid.

Comment: If you don't have it checked out, then wouldn't the app not work due to missing generated js?