# Customizing the specific output files for various Typescript input files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, typescript

I've got a web project using TypeScript that has some reasonably complex requirements for the compiled output files. So for instance, I need all the *.ts files in one directory to compile down to one single .js file, and all the *.ts files in another directory to compile down to a different .js file. (It's more complex than that, but you get the idea.)

I've been able to get this working using the tsc.exe command-line, using input files and what-not, but I'd like to be able to use MSBuild .targets files - among other things, using tsc.exe from the command-line seems to be pretty poorly supported on continuous integration servers, where it can be located who-knows-where, and certainly isn't likely to be in the path.

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651172/typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save), it seems like I should be able to do this using custom build targets. So I've created a custom version of Microsoft.TypeScript.targets, and in addition to the default "CompileTypeScript" target, I've created a second one, "PayboardApiV10", so that the relevant part looks like so:

```
  <Target Name="CompileTypeScript" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false'">
    <Message Text="Compiling TypeScript files normally" Importance="high"/>
    <VsTsc
      ToolPath="$(TscToolPath)"
      ToolExe="$(TscToolExe)"
      Configurations="$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations)"
      FullPathsToFiles="@(TypeScriptCompile)"
      YieldDuringToolExecution="$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)"
      OutFile="$(TypeScriptOutFile)"
      OutDir="$(TypeScriptOutDir)"
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedJavascript" ItemName="GeneratedJavascript" />
    </VsTsc>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PayboardApiV10" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false'">
    <Message Text="Compiling TypeScript files for Payboard API v1.0" Importance="high"  />
    <VsTsc
      ToolPath="$(TscToolPath)"
      ToolExe="$(TscToolExe)"
      Configurations="$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations)"
      FullPathsToFiles="@(TypeScriptCompile)"
      YieldDuringToolExecution="$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)"
      OutFile="Payboard.js"
      OutDir="$(ProjectDir)api\v1.0\"
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedJavascript" ItemName="GeneratedJavascript" />
    </VsTsc>
  </Target>
```

And then I've specified a "CustomTool" in my project configuration for the specific files that I'd like to get picked up by the "PayboardApiV10" build target, like so:

[image: Custom build tool spec]

I should note that I have no idea if I'm doing this bit correctly. I can't seem to find any documentation on it, and the only examples I've been able to find are from that [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651172/typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save). And more to the point, when I run my builds, *all* the TS files in my project get caught up in the first build target, including the ones for which I've specified "MSBuild:PayboardApiV10" for the custom tool. The "PayboardApiV10" tool never seems to get run, i.e., I never see the message "Compiling TypeScript files for Payboard API v1.0".

So two questions:

(1) Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

(2) If this is generally the right way to do it, any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any output when you save the file in the output window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking this same question over on the TypeScript forums (https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/455781). The conclusions I drew from the conversation there:

- There isn't a great way to do it now.
- The best hacky way to do it now is probably the way that I was doing it, namely, with batch files, post-build events, and checking the compiled files into source. Other folks recommended Grunt, or the ASP.NET MVC bundling mechanism (the latter won't work in my scenario); I've also used the r.js minifier in the past. And these will work; but to reiterate, none of these are really very good solutions.
- The best way to do it in the future will be to create "library projects" of TypeScript files, so that all TS files in a given project get compiled together; and then you can reference the library TS projects from your main Web project, and will automatically get the compiled files merged into your main `~/Scripts` folder. But that will require support from the TS team - which Jon Turner basically indicated would be coming, though he didn't say when. (See also https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/571.)

Answer (score 0):

The direction you're going is the optimal way (on save). In the meantime you can use [post-build events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) to transform the typescript. Right click on your project and select properties. Select Build Events and in the Post-Build area you can specify command line parameters to use tsc.exe.

On the direction you're going (compile on save) I think the project file may be missing the following on each file you want compiled:

```
<TypeScriptCompile Include="app.ts" />
```

The configuration is also likely missing the environment settings.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More information on both methods is available at this [TypeScript wiki page](http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save).

Comment: Thanks, Dustin. I've got the `TypeScriptCompile Include='' />` bits in my .csproj file for everything, and same with the `<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>` bits. And those are working, as evidenced by the fact that all those files are getting picked up and compiled appropriately.

Comment: Also, I know that I can use the post-build events to manually run the tsc.exe file. And I may yet be forced to do that. But I was hoping to get a more standard way of doing it - and I was also having trouble getting tsc.exe to be found when I was running it that way, when deploying to Azure through git/kudu.