# How to use AngularJS / TypeScript 1.4 with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, typescript, typescript1.4

I'm trying to use these [AngularJS TS Definitions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/) in Visual Studio 2012, but unfortunately I get plenty errors (like: '=' expected.) and MSBuild is not able to compile TypeScript.

I would love to use the TypeScript Options e.g. to compile my TS files in a single JS file (as described here: [Typescript compile to single file on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651172/typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save)) as well as a compilation on our build server. So WebEssentials is no option for me.

**Edit:**

The build log looks like this:

```
[...]
1>[...]\jquery.d.ts(2768,34): error TS1005: Build: ',' expected.
1>[...]\angularjs\angular.d.ts(878,50): error TS1005: Build: ',' expected.
1>[...]\angular.d.ts(878,57): error TS1005: Build: ',' expected.
[...]
```

The WebEssential Compilation / Preview works fine...

Comment: Have you verified you have installed the plugin for TypeScript support? In 2012 I think it's Web Essentials, though there could be a specific plugin for TS support.

Comment: "WebEssential 2012" and the official "TypeScript 1.0 Tools for Visual Studio 2012" are installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 1.4 isn't available for Visual Studio 2012.

You need to use a different IDE to access the latest versions of TypeScript - i.e. Visual Studio 2013, Atom, WebStorm, Sublime Text, Eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

If both, Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 is installed, Visual Studio 2012 can be forced to use TypeScript version 1.4 by setting `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` in the csproj and by installing *TypeScript 1.4 for Visual Studio 2013* next to *TypeScript 1.0 for Visual Studio 2012*. However JSLint needs to be deactivated in WebEssentials (Tools > Options > Web Essentials > JSHint > Enable JSHint = False / required a VS restart), otherwise there are plenty errors.

Worked for me but will not be a solution for most people, so Steve Fentons answer will remain the accepted one.